# Unable to instantiate EWS ExchangeService in Runnable or Spring Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, exchangewebservices, timertask

I have a EWS Service inside a `TimerTask` but it is throwing Exception while instantiating `new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2)` and it is not working in spring-web-mvc Controller method that anootated with `@RequestMapping` but instantiation works very well in Non-`Runnable` Class.

```
public class AutoEmailTicketing extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        service.setCredentials(new WebCredentials(email, password));
        service.autodiscoverUrl(email, new RedirectionUrlCallback());
        service.setTraceEnabled(true);
        Folder inbox = Folder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
    }
}
```

Used jar...

```
commons-codec-1.7.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar
EWSJavaAPI_1.2.1.jar
EWSJavaAPI_1.2original.jar
EWSJavaAPIWithJars_1.2.1.jar
jcifs-1.3.17.jar
httpclient-4.2.5.jar
httpcore-4.2.4.jar
```

Exception log are given below...

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createDefault(SchemeRegistryFactory.java:47)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:93)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeServiceBase.<init>(Unknown Source)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.mbl.messaging.service.ews.AutoEmailTicketing.run(AutoEmailTicketing.java:4)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last find a solution at [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780806/aws-java-sdk-error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror). I have Used ...

```
httpclient-4.2.jar
httpcore-4.2.jar
joda-time-2.9.9.jar
```

I don't know `joda-time` depends on it or not.